# How to define multiple default routes in ASP.NET Core for multiple roles?

Tags: asp.net, routes, asp.net-core-mvc, endpoint

I am using this code for default route in startup.cs:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default1",
                pattern: "{controller=Employee}/{action=list}/{id?}")
                .RequireAuthorization();
        });
```

How can I define multiple default routes for multiple roles?

I have 2 roles "Admin" and "User". I want to use separate default route for each role.

Comment: I do not think it is possible. Have you tried using 'RequireAuthorization ("PolicyName")'?
Or you could use a custom middleware where you read the role and change the 'BasePath' of request.

Comment: @SteeBono thank you for your answer, I use RequireAuthorization ("PolicyName") but it doesn't work too...

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario as far as I understand you want to hold only 1 role per User. If you are using Identity for Authentication and Authorization, you can get user role after their login request was successful. And then based on their role, you can redirect them to an action. But this is not a method I recommend, because in general Users have more than 1 role, maybe you can use "contains" methods to redirect users if they have a specific role.

Here is the code I am talking about:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Username, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                User user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(Input.Username);
                IList <string> role = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
                if (role[0] == "Admin")
                    return RedirectToAction("Privacy", "Home");
                else if (role[0] == "User")
                    return RedirectToAction("someAction", "Home");
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
```

Comment: this is true.
but after any user by any role login , and input the main address (mysite.com) I want each role automatically redirect to specified page.

Comment: So you are saying you will also create new roles during runtime? You can achieve that by making the action names dynamic, you can use a List<string>. But the problem is, you will also need to define the actions which you can not do it on runtime. You need to add Controllers and actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by creating a middleware where you manage the route where you will redirect users.

```
public class RouteMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public RouteMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Example of service to retrieve user roles, claims and so on
        var roleService = context.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IRoleService)) as IRoleService;

        if (context.Request.Path.HasValue)
        {
            // if you add 'BasePath' on request, your request will become like this:
            // before: https://www.yourdomain.com/original_path
            // after:  https://www.yourdomain.com/base_path/original_path

            // so for example, you can do something like: 
            // path: https://www.yourdomain.com/user?id=12345
            // if admin: https://www.yourdomain.com/admin/user?id=12345
            // if other: https://www.yourdomain.com/other/user?id=12345

            string @base = null;
            string @path = null;

            var userRoles = await roleService.GetUserRoleAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            if(userRoles.Contains("ADMIN"))
            {
                @base = "/admin";
                
                // you can also edit path here
                @path = context.Request.Path;
            }
            else 
            {
                @base = "/other";
                
                // you can also edit path here
                @path = context.Request.Path;
            }
            
            context.Request.PathBase = @base;
            context.Request.Path = @path;
            
            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

and in your startup.cs

```
app.UseMiddleware<RouteMiddleware>();
```

I haven't tested that snippet, it's just an example to give you an idea of how you might proceed.